# Rugged equivalent to 'git ls-tree'

Tags: git, rugged, git-ls-files

In a bare repository I can type `$ git ls-tree -r master`. (this is sort of the same thing I can get in a none-bare repos with the command `git ls-files` )

for a full list of files and their sha refs in a git repository.

With Rugged, how do I get that list of files in a particular branch or master?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is rugged's Tree object. If you have a commit, say from `commit = repo.head.target`, you can get the files in that commit's tree by accessing it as an array:

```
tree = commit.tree
puts tree[0].filename
```

See https://github.com/libgit2/rugged#tree-objects for more examples

Answer (score 0):

In rugged 1.2.0 you can do:

```
repo.index.entries.map { |e| e[:path] }
```